# can't add columns in multicolumns for django-cms

Tags: django, django-cms

1. On a newly created virtualenv, in a newly created folder, I run the djangocms-installer. Everything runs fine, install is brand new.
2. "manage.py check" and "manage.py cms check"
3. "manage.py runserver"
4. I create a new page "test"

So far everything is fine. Then:

1. I click on the right icon of content and add a "multicolumn" [2 columns of 50%]

Here, no error shows up in the console. But even publish, save, restart server or whatever, the "multicolumn" is shown as empty. So I try to add one manually:

1. I click on the right icon of multicolumn and add a "column" [size 50%]

Then the below shows up:

```
(env) C:\Users\Raphael\django-cms-workspace>manage.py runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found
August 03, 2014 - 17:12:12
Django version 1.6.5, using settings 'my_test_site.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[03/Aug/2014 17:12:21] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[03/Aug/2014 17:12:22] "GET /en/ HTTP/1.1" 200 46801
[03/Aug/2014 17:12:22] "GET /en/favicon.ico/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2900
[03/Aug/2014 17:12:22] "GET /en/admin/cms/page/?language=en&page_id=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 10936
[03/Aug/2014 17:12:30] "GET /en/admin/cms/page/add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6030
[03/Aug/2014 17:12:30] "GET /static/cms/js/modules/cms.changeform.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[03/Aug/2014 17:12:30] "GET /en/admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2344
[03/Aug/2014 17:12:30] "GET /en/admin/cms/page/resolve/?model=cms.page&pk=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 4
[03/Aug/2014 17:12:42] "POST /en/admin/cms/page/add/?language=en HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[03/Aug/2014 17:12:43] "GET /en/admin/cms/page/ HTTP/1.1" 200 13608
[03/Aug/2014 17:12:43] "GET /en/admin/cms/page/resolve/?model=cms.page&pk=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 9
[03/Aug/2014 17:12:43] "GET /en/test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 18315
[03/Aug/2014 17:12:44] "GET /en/admin/cms/page/?page_id=5 HTTP/1.1" 200 13473
[03/Aug/2014 17:12:49] "GET /en/admin/cms/page/5/en/preview/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[03/Aug/2014 17:12:49] "GET /en/test/?edit&language=en HTTP/1.1" 200 18317
[03/Aug/2014 17:12:50] "GET /en/admin/cms/page/?page_id=5&language=en HTTP/1.1" 200 13473
[03/Aug/2014 17:12:54] "GET /en/admin/cms/page/5/en/publish/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[03/Aug/2014 17:12:55] "GET /en/test/?edit_off HTTP/1.1" 200 10295
[03/Aug/2014 17:12:56] "GET /en/admin/cms/page/?page_id=5&language=en HTTP/1.1" 200 13516
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:09] "GET /en/admin/cms/page/resolve/?model=cms.page&pk=6 HTTP/1.1" 200 9
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:12] "GET /en/test/?edit HTTP/1.1" 200 18597
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:21] "POST /en/admin/cms/page/add-plugin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 184
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:21] "GET /en/admin/cms/page/edit-plugin/60/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4102
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:21] "GET /en/admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2344
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:27] "POST /en/admin/cms/page/edit-plugin/60/ HTTP/1.1" 500 238272
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:27] "GET /en/admin/cms/page/resolve/?model=cms.page&pk=5 HTTP/1.1" 200 9
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:28] "GET /en/test/?edit HTTP/1.1" 200 20867
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:39] "POST /en/admin/cms/page/add-plugin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 250
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:39] "GET /en/admin/cms/page/edit-plugin/61/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3050
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:39] "GET /en/admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2344
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:46] "POST /en/admin/cms/page/edit-plugin/61/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2046
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:46] "GET /en/admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2344
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:46] "GET /en/admin/cms/page/resolve/?model=cms.page&pk=5 HTTP/1.1" 200 9
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:47] "GET /en/test/?edit HTTP/1.1" 200 23408
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\socket.py", line 391, in write
    return self._sock.send(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:47] "GET /en/test/?edit HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 64712)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\socket.py", line 391, in write
    return self._sock.send(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\socketserver.py", line 610, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\socketserver.py", line 345, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\Raphael\django-cms-workspace\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 126, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\socketserver.py", line 666, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 126, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:47] "GET /en/test/?edit HTTP/1.1" 200 23408
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:47] "GET /static/cms/js/libs/class.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:47] "GET /static/cms/css/cms.base.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:47] "GET /static/cms/js/libs/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:48] "GET /static/cms/js/modules/jquery.ui.nestedsortable.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:48] "GET /static/cms/js/modules/cms.modal.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:48] "GET /static/cms/js/modules/cms.base.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:48] "GET /static/cms/js/modules/jquery.ui.custom.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:48] "GET /static/cms/js/modules/cms.clipboard.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:48] "GET /static/cms/js/modules/cms.structureboard.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:48] "GET /static/cms/js/modules/cms.toolbar.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:48] "GET /static/cms/js/modules/cms.plugins.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:48] "GET /static/cms/js/modules/cms.sideframe.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[03/Aug/2014 17:13:48] "GET /static/cms/img/toolbar/sprite_toolbar.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0

(env) C:\Users\Raphael\django-cms-workspace>

(env) C:\Users\Raphael\django-cms-workspace>manage.py cms check
←[1m********************************←[0m
←[1mChecking django CMS installation←[0m
←[1m********************************←[0m

←[1mSekizai←[0m
←[1m=======←[0m

  - Sekizai is installed ←[32;1m[OK]←[0m
  - Sekizai template context processor is installed ←[32;1m[OK]←[0m
  - Sekizai namespaces 'js' and 'css' found in 'page.html' ←[32;1m[OK]←[0m
  - Sekizai namespaces 'js' and 'css' found in 'feature.html' ←[32;1m[OK]←[0m

Sekizai configuration okay ←[32;1m[OK]←[0m

←[1mInternationalization←[0m
←[1m====================←[0m

  - New style CMS_LANGUAGES ←[32;1m[OK]←[0m

←[1mDeprecated settings←[0m
←[1m===================←[0m

  - No deprecated settings found ←[34;1m[SKIP]←[0m

←[1mPlugin instances←[0m
←[1m================←[0m

  - Plugin instances of 3 types found in the database ←[32;1m[OK]←[0m
  - MultiColumnPlugin has 1 unsaved instances ←[31;1m[ERROR]←[0m

There are potentially serious problems with the plugins in your database.
Even if your site works, you should run the 'manage.py cms list plugins'
command and then the 'manage.py cms delete_orphaned_plugins' command.
This will alter your database; read the documentation before using it. ←[31;1m[ERROR]←[0m

←[1mPresence of "copy_relations"←[0m
←[1m============================←[0m


All plugins and page/title extensions have "copy_relations" method if needed. ←[32;1m[OK]←[0m

←[1mUsage of deprecated placeholder_tags←[0m
←[1m====================================←[0m



←[1mOVERALL RESULTS←[0m
←[1m===============←[0m

←[31;1m2 errors!←[0m
←[34;1m1 checks skipped!←[0m
←[32;1m8 checks successful!←[0m

←[31;1mPlease check the errors above←[0m

CommandError:

(env) C:\Users\Raphael\django-cms-workspace>
```

I have tried a dozen of times, ran the commands the cms check told me to run, but no matter what I try, it seems I can't have multi column content. Which is very weird, as the "demo page" with 3 columns works like a charm.

Any idea ?

just for info:

in virtual env:

```
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
    (1, 6, 5, 'final', 0)

(env) C:\Users\Raphael\django-cms-workspace>pip freeze | grep cms
django-cms==3.0.3
djangocms-admin-style==0.2.2
djangocms-column==1.3
djangocms-file==0.0.1
djangocms-flash==0.0.2
djangocms-googlemap==0.0.5
djangocms-inherit==0.0.1
djangocms-installer==0.5.3
djangocms-link==1.3.5
djangocms-picture==0.0.2
djangocms-style==1.3
djangocms-teaser==0.0.1
djangocms-text-ckeditor==2.1.6
djangocms-video==0.0.1
```

This seems to be a local issue, related to something killing the connection. I've turned off antivirus and firewall, checked windows defender was of and tried again, same problem... I'm gonna cry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this probably isn't helpful, but django-cms is documented to require 2.6, 2.7 or 3.3, see here: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/getting_started/integrate.html#requirements. It is currently being CI tested under 3.4 too, but I wonder if there are some dependencies that do not work yet under 3.4?

Comment: xrange() though won't work with any python 3 versions. The weird things is that, in django packages, djangocms-column is not reported to be python 3 compatible, yet it is automatically installed by the djangocms installer with no warning... By the way, I think I have every single one of your videos downloaded on my desktop, thanks for those ones.

Comment: give you the bounty, anyway, problem is solved. in my below answer. better the bounty to go to someone.

Comment: I totally don't deserve this! Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is a final solution, but debugging through, i came to a silent failure. Basically, xrange() while i'm using python 3.

It did not throw an exception, but column were not saved. I made a pull request. Still, I'll award someone with my bounty. Not sure how I'll choose though...

I made a pull request on github:
https://github.com/divio/djangocms-column/pull/17